# Python sqlite3 how do I check equality with potentially null python value

Tags: python, sql, haskell, sqlite

It appears that in SQL `null = null` returns false. I can see this making sense in some circumstances where `null` means unknown/unspecified, but often `null` is used very intentionally to mean known and well defined absence, in those situations I would love for `null = null` to be true.

What is the proper way to deal with this when using `sqlite3`? As currently doing anything like:

```
c.execute('select * from foo where bar = ?', [bar])
```

will break if `bar` is `None`, whereas I very much want it to return every row where `bar` is `null`. This all works seamlessly in Haskell's persistent which is what I am using on the other end, (`FooBar ==. Nothing`), so I was hoping for something similarly clean on the Python end.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL `NULL = NULL` is indeed false (NULL actually IIRC, but that's also false). What you need in your example instead is the `is` operator `'select * from foo where bar is ?'`

I'm guessing the behavior in persistent is to choose `=` or `is` depending on whether or not the value is of type `Maybe a` or not, Python doesn't have that kind of information (at least not in the sqlite module of the standard library).

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL, then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not, then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is 1 (true). It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to evaluate to NULL. Operators IS and IS NOT have the same precedence as =.

Source: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: Yes I'm fairly sure persistent switches to `is` for `Nothing` and uses `=` for `Just` / non-`Maybe` types. I was kind of worried that was the answer, I guess I'll just do some weird hacks with `.format` to insert the right operator. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what your use case is, but you normally shouldn't need any switches or formatting, just use the "right" operator. Unless you're automatically generating the queries that is, but it didn't sound like you were doing that

Comment: Oops, I didn't properly read the part in yellow as I had assumed it was the same as what I read earlier. So it seems like I can just always use `is` and get nice behavior where `null` is considered equal to itself. Is this a sqlite specific thing? As I may end up using a different database if performance becomes an issue, and I read elsewhere that in SQL `is` can only be followed by `null` or `not null`.

Comment: @semicolon I don't have the SQL standard on hand, but it seems like Oracle DB and Microsoft SQL Server indeed only support the `is [not] null` syntax; So this indeed seems like a nonstandard SQL extension. Note that SQLite is different in a few important ways from other mainstream Databases and those have significant differences between them too, so full portability between databases isn't something you should necessarily expect unless you restrict yourself to a very small subset of SQL.